# Determine scroll offset for UITextView in UIScrollVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have `UITextView` and other views below and after textView in `UIScrollView`.
When user enter text I change textView frame height on textView.contentSize.height.
The idea is save the possibility for user see all text and other elements.
I have some issue. When user tap I want to scroll to this line. And this must seems like:

[image]

I can't determine how calculate offset and always scroll to current caret like.

My initial screen:

[image]

All views are subviews of `UIScrollView`.
Every time when user enter `@"\n"` I change `UITextView` frame:

```
CGRect textViewFrame = textView.frame;
CGSize textViewContentSize = textView.contentSize;
NSLog(@"textView content size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(textViewContentSize));
textViewFrame.size.height = textViewContentSize.height;
[textView setFrame:textViewFrame];
```

And I increment `UIScrollView` contentSize.
My problem - I don't understand how to scroll to textView's **CURSOR** when it under keyboard.
I try do something:

```
CGPoint cursorPosition = [textView caretRectForPosition:textView.selectedTextRange.start].origin;

CGPoint relativeCursorPoint = [textView convertPoint:cursorPosition toView:scrollView];

if(textView.isFirstResponder && relativeCursorPoint.y >= scrollViewFrame.size.height + scrollView.contentOffset.y)
{
    int offset = relativeCursorPoint.y - scrollViewFrame.size.height + 18.0f;
    //int offset = textViewRect.origin.y - scrollViewFrame.size.height + 18.0f;
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, offset) animated:YES];
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Are you asking how to scroll the view to be just above the keyboard? I'm finding it a little difficult to understand your question could you clarify it? Thanks!

Comment: @NinjaLikesCheez, yes, something like this.

Comment: The length of text(which you entered in TextField) is almost equal to height and scroll of the TextField.

Comment: @G.Ganesh, :) I asked about textView and textView resing in scrollView

Answer (score 1):

[image]

A.) To achieve a similar effect to the Apple Notes scrolling + keyboard dismissal, I started by adding a UITextView inside a UIScrollView.

B.) Then add self as observer for changes in keyboard:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textViewDidBeginEditing:) name:UITextViewTextDidBeginEditingNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(keyboardWillChangeFrame:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

C.) Then when the user hits the textview / textfield, the method below is called. You grab the beginning height and end height of the keyboard, and set a variable called keyboardHeight to the endHeight value (used later).

The 'difference' being calculated below is used to move the text up and down as the user moves the autocorrection / suggestion bar up and down. If you don't want this you can set 'autocorrectionType' on the textView to false.

```
-(void)keyboardWillChangeFrame:(NSNotification *)n {

    float beginHeight = [[n.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;
    float endHeight = [[n.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;
    float difference = beginHeight-endHeight;
    keyBoardHeight = endHeight; //set the var

    //animate change
    if (difference != 0){ //animate frame change in your textview }
}
```

D.) On the textViewDidBegin method, move the UIScrollview to the top of the screen, so the textview is flush with the top (setContentOffset).

You calculate the height of the textview as it should be between the top of the view and the top of the keyboard, called 'initialTVHeight' below.

You should force the textview to have its scrolling enabled, so set the textView.contentSize to the minimum size (initialTVHeight) + one pixel - this forces scroll.

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {

    //need to move the tv up to the top
    float yOff = 0;
    yOff += durationCell.frame.size.height;
    yOff += reminderCell.frame.size.height;
    yOff += fixedCell.frame.size.height;
    yOff += repeatCell.frame.size.height;
    [mainScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, yOff) animated:true];

    //resize the textview to meet the top of the keyboard
    float padding = 0; //padding between keyboard and last line in the textview
    initialTVHeight = h - 60 - keyBoardHeight - padding; //the height when text does not overflow
    textTV.frame = CGRectMake(0, textTV.frame.origin.y, w, initialTVHeight); //set the frame to that size

    //if smaller than minimum, increase (if editing existing text)
    if (textTV.contentSize.height < initialTVHeight){
       textTV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(w, initialTVHeight+1); //force initial scroll
    }
}
```

E.) This method updates the textView contentSize to the minimum height to ensure scrolling is enabled (ie. if there are only two lines of text, the user can still bounce scroll). Where the textView content is longer than the initial size, allow it to grow naturally.

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    //require minimum height for scroll
    if (textTV.contentSize.height < initialTVHeight){ //content height comes in under, force scroll
        textTV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(w, initialTVHeight+1); //adding one forces scroll
    }
}
```

F.) Add these methods, that make sure the keyboard is only dismissed by user dragging (not by user entering a new line)

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if ([scrollView isEqual:textTV]){
        enableDragDismiss = true;
    }
}
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    if ([scrollView isEqual:textTV]){
        enableDragDismiss = false;
    }
}
```

G.) Finally, add this method, which dismisses the keyboard if the user drags below the height of the keyboard.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (enableDragDismiss && [scrollView isEqual:textTV]){

        float y = [textTV.panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view].y;
        float keyboardY = h-keyBoardHeight;

        if (y > keyboardY){
            enableDragDismiss = false; //allow only once
            [textTV resignFirstResponder];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                                  delay:0.0f
                 usingSpringWithDamping:1.0f
                  initialSpringVelocity:0.8f
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^{
                                 mainScroller.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
                                 textTV.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             }];

            float yOff = 60;
            yOff += durationCell.frame.size.height;
            yOff += reminderCell.frame.size.height;
            yOff += fixedCell.frame.size.height;
            yOff += repeatCell.frame.size.height;
            textTV.frame = CGRectMake(0, textTV.frame.origin.y, w, h-yOff);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you are trying to scroll the UITextView to be 'above' the keyboard then you can use `-[UITextView textViewDidBeginEditing:]` to modify the content offset for your scrollView on initial touch, however if you're wanting to scroll everytime the user adds a newline or something similar you should be able to use `-[UITextView shouldChangeTextInRange:]` as follows.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        // User has pressed 'return' and entered a new line
        // change the content offset + height of line text
        self.textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(x, y);


        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

`UITextView` inherits from `UIScrollView` so you can change content offset like you would in `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is working for me

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}    

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        activeField=textField;
    }

    -(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification{
        float viewWidth = 1024;
        float viewHeight = 654;
        NSDictionary *keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
        CGSize keyboardSize = [[keyboardInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
        float keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.width;
        CGRect viewableAreaFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, viewWidth, viewHeight - keyboardHeight);
        CGRect txtDemoFrame = [activeField.superview convertRect:activeField.frame toView:self.view];
        if (!CGRectContainsRect(viewableAreaFrame, txtDemoFrame)) {
            // We need to calculate the new Y offset point.
            //float scrollPointY = viewHeight - keyboardHeight;
            // Don't forget that the scroller should go to its original position
            // so store the current Y point of the content offset.
            self.originalScrollerOffsetY = self.SCRVMain.contentOffset.y;
            // Finally, scroll.
            [self.SCRVMain setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, [activeField.superview convertPoint:activeField.frame.origin toView:self.view].y-200) animated:YES];
        }
    }
    -(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification{
        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        self.SCRVMain.contentInset = contentInsets;
        self.SCRVMain.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
        [self.SCRVMain setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, self.originalScrollerOffsetY) animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my textViewDidChange: I've implemented such a solution (apologies for a VERY RAW code ;)):

```
NSString* substringToSelection = [textView.text substringToIndex:textView.selectedRange.location];
UIFont* textFont = textView.font;

CGRect boundingRect = [substringToSelection boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : textFont} context:nil];
CGRect translatedRect = [textView convertRect:boundingRect toView:self.scrollView];

if (!CGRectContainsPoint(self.scrollView.bounds, CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(translatedRect), CGRectGetMaxY(translatedRect))))
{
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:translatedRect animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I like this solution but have a comment and question: First, the CGRectContainsPoint() check might not be necessary since the `-scrollRectToVisible:animated:` method does nothing if the area is already visible. Second, the solution seems to scroll down just enough for the top of the area to be visible. In my case (on iOS7) this is showing the first few pixels of the line (where the cursor exists) and not the entire line. Are you seeing this behaviour as well? I got around this by adding:

    `translatedRect.origin.y += textFont.capHeight;`